# JSONDecoder codec can't decode byte 0xe0

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to decode byte array with json.JSONDecoder

```
decoder = json.JSONDecoder()
result, index = decoder.raw_decode(data)
```

but sometimes I get error `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position 1: unexpected end of data`
Does anyone have a clue what is wrong, do I need to pass additional parameters to JSONDecoder constructor ?

Comment: You have invalid data in your JSON input. Where does the `data` value come from?

Answer (score 2):

As `0xe0` in some encodings is small latin letter e with grave, i.e. "è", I suspect that your input file is not utf-8.

The `JSONDecoder` constructor takes an `encoding` parameter. Tell the decoder the actual encoding of your input, and hopefully this should work.